# What kind of object in Java do i need to create for parsing an array in a JSON

Tags: java, json

Ive been creating Java classes and objects for parsing this JSON:
[openweathermap.org](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk)
and its working great, but theres a part i cant understand what to built for it to work, its the array part (first row - object named "weather"), i keep trying to figure it out but nothing seems to work, any help please?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.json.org/java/ It is very simple to use.

If you have a String JSON, you call just call in the constructor

```
String jsonStr = "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-0.13,\"lat\":51.51},\"weather\":[{\"id\":721,\"main\":\"Haze\",\"description\":\"haze\",\"icon\":\"50n\"}],\"base\":\"cmc stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":290.69,\"pressure\":1019,\"humidity\":72,\"temp_min\":287.04,\"temp_max\":294.15},\"wind\":{\"speed\":2.1,\"deg\":200},\"clouds\":{\"all\":0},\"dt\":1440199100,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":5091,\"message\":0.005,\"country\":\"GB\",\"sunrise\":1440132986,\"sunset\":1440184167},\"id\":2643743,\"name\":\"London\",\"cod\":200}";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray weather = json.getJSONArray("weather");
```

Comment: I will help you to help me, for this Json [json](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk)                   Ive built a class called WeatherData that holds inside a composiotion of the classes you can see in the Json (coord, base, main, etc..) and its working just fine, my question is, what kind of class do I need to built for the "weather" type class to parse it right? btw, I'm using Gson. thanks.

Comment: weather should be a type of `JSONArray` in your class variable

Comment: in my classes thers no supose to be any mentitioning to json.. I'm asking what does weather needs to be in ordered to let Gson parser know him? an ArrayList? cause its not working

Answer (score 0):

The simpleat class that all JSON Libraries can deserialize to is `HashMap.class`.

The simplest class for an array of objects is `HashMap[].class`

Comment: for this Json [json](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk) Ive built a class called WeatherData that holds inside a composiotion of the classes you can see in the Json (coord, base, main, etc..) and its working just fine, my question is, what kind of class do I need to built for the "weather" type class to parse it right? btw, I'm using Gson. thanks.

Comment: try `WeatherData[] data = new Gson().fromJson(input, WeatherData[].class);`